# How to change color of Done and Cancel button of select Field in sencha touch 2 framework

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2

// Hi i am using sencha touch 2.0 framework . I used selectfield in my project the thing is that i need to change the color of done and cancel button of the selectfield. But those picker buttons are not visible in browser but appearing in android device. So how can i apply color to those two buttons.

provide some details and related posts too if possible

Comment: This question is great for everyone searching for the appropriate CSS selectors for these in general.

Answer (score 2):

This will override all cancel button's styles in your app.
Include the following in your CSS and include your CSS after sencha's CSS:

```
/*Cancel Button styles overriding*/
.x-toolbar-dark .x-button, .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-back::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-forward::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-button, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-back::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-forward::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-back::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-forward::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-back::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-forward::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-back::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-forward::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-back::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-forward::after { 
    background-color: #303030;
    background-image: none;
}
.x-toolbar-dark .x-button, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-button, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top-color: #000000;
    color: white;
}
.x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-pressing::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-pressed::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-active, .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-active::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-pressing::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-pressed::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-active, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-button.x-button-active::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-pressing::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-pressed::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-active, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-active::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-pressing::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-pressed::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-active, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer.x-button-active::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-pressing::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-pressed::after, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-active, .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-active::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-pressing::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-pressed::after, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-active, .x-toolbar .x-toolbar-dark .x-field-select .x-component-outer::before.x-button-active::after {
    background-color: #383838;
    background-image: none;
}

/*Done Button styles overriding*/
.x-button.x-button-action, .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-back::after, .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-forward::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-back::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-forward::after, .x-button.x-button-action-round, .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-back::after, .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-forward::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-round, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-back::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-forward::after, .x-button.x-button-action-small, .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-back::after, .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-forward::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-small, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-back::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-forward::after {
    background-color: #303030;
    background-image: none;
}
.x-button.x-button-action, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action, .x-button.x-button-action-round, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-round, .x-button.x-button-action-small, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-small {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top-color: #000000;
    color: white;
}
.x-button.x-button-action.x-button-pressing, .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-pressing::after, .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-pressed, .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-pressed::after, .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-active, .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-active::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-pressing::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-pressed::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-active, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action.x-button-active::after, .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-pressing, .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-pressing::after, .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-pressed, .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-pressed::after, .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-active, .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-active::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-pressing::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-pressed::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-active, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-round.x-button-active::after, .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-pressing, .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-pressing::after, .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-pressed, .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-pressed::after, .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-active, .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-active::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-pressing, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-pressing::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-pressed, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-pressed::after, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-active, .x-toolbar .x-button.x-button-action-small.x-button-active::after {
    background-color: #383838;
    background-image: none;
}
```